# Optimizing calculation query

Tags: sql-server, optimization, query

In a legacy project I've the following query:

```
SELECT 
    concat(SR_PO, '-', SR_RlsSequence) as Order,
    count(*) as Todo,
    sum(isnull(SR_Enabled,0)) as ToLoad,
    sum(isnull(SR_Done,0)) as Loaded,
    sum(isnull(SR_Enabled,0))-sum(isnull(SR_Done,0))-sum(isnull(Rejected,0)) as Missing,
    count(EndTime3) as Quot,
    sum(isnull(Rejected,0)) as Scrapped
FROM [Edgebanding]
WHERE concat(SR_PO, '-', SR_RlsSequence) IN ('100063-100', '100063-101', '100063-103', '100063-104')
GROUP BY by concat(SR_PO, '-', SR_RlsSequence)
```

But its too expensive, especially when the IN parameters are lots. Any ideas concerning an optimization? please consider that I cannot use a stored procedure.

Estimated Query plan is uploaded [here](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rykDeIWQ8).

Comment: Could you add the actual execution plan to [PasteThePlan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)? Otherwise table definition and some sample data could work too.

Comment: Here it is, [link](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rykDeIWQ8)

Comment: Is it possible to include the actual plan?

Comment: Look the link above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try applying the filter

(`WHERE concat(SR_PO, '-', SR_RlsSequence) IN ('100063-100', '100063-101', '100063-103', '100063-104')`)

Directly on the index instead of it being implemented as a filter further in the execution plan.

[image]
You can do this by not applying functions on columns in your `where` clause and adding an index. The group by is also changed to work without the function.

Query adaptation:

```
SELECT 
    concat(SR_PO, '-', SR_RlsSequence) as [Order],
    count(*) as Todo,
    sum(isnull(SR_Enabled,0)) as ToLoad,
    sum(isnull(SR_Done,0)) as Loaded,
    sum(isnull(SR_Enabled,0))-sum(isnull(SR_Done,0))-sum(isnull(Rejected,0)) as Missing,
    count(EndTime3) as Quot,
    sum(isnull(Rejected,0)) as Scrapped
FROM [Edgebanding]
WHERE SR_PO = '100063' AND SR_RlsSequence IN ('100','101','103','104')
GROUP BY SR_PO, SR_RlsSequence;
```

And index:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_SR_PO_SR_RlsSequence
ON [dbo].[Edgebanding](SR_PO,SR_RlsSequence)
INCLUDE(SR_Enabled,SR_Done,Rejected,EndTime3);
```